# Removing or modifying Python Console shortcut on PyCharm's switcher

Tags: emacs, pycharm

When activating the switcher on Intellij I usually use Ctrl+P / Ctrl+N to navigate between listed items (yes, I use Emacs keymap).
Problem is, in PyCharm Ctrl+P opens the Python Console (actually, P opens the Python Console, but Ctrl+P is identified as such by the IDE).

Is there any way to modify or even remove the Python Console shortcut in PyCharm's switcher?

Answer (score 1):

While I did not found how to modify or remove the aforementioned shortcut in PyCharm's switcher, I found that the "Recent Files" dialog to be exactly what I needed the switcher to be.
Just change your shortcut to point to "Recent Files" instead of "Switcher".